# How can I have different events for the same CustomInfoWindow

Tags: java, android, google-maps, syntax, syntax-error

So I know my question is a bit weird but I will explain what I mean:
So I have a customInfoWindow and about 20 markers.
I have successfully added a onclick listener with 0 errors.
The thing is that I like want some way that that listener is for one custominfwindow marker and for the other custominfowindow marker have a different event.
For example if you click on the custominfowindow on sydney it displays a toast and if you click on the custominfowindow of India it opens a  layout.What I guess I can do is make the onclick listner local so the code is not applied anywhere out of sydney. I don't know how to add the code for it.
Could someone please help me with this question.
I am new to this programming so I quite well don't understand a quarter of things so please help me with this.
Just in case code for onclick listner in MapsActivity:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.util.Map;
//Class starts;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        openIndia();
    }
 public void openIndia(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,India.class);
        startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Also my code is way more longer but to save the person who answers and my time I only gave the code which has to be changed or useful.
Another than this i dont think any more code is needed.
Just in case if it is required please inform me.

Comment: Please give the direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to tag the marker:

```
Marker indiaMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(....).title("India").snippet());
indiaMarker.setTag("India"); // the tag could be anything, an id maybe ?

Marker sydneyMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(....).title("Sydney").snippet());
sydneyMarker.setTag("Sydney");
```

...

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        if("India".equals(marker.getTag())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,India.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if("Sydney".equals(marker.getTag())) {
            // showToast() or whatever you want to   
        }
    }
```

The relevant documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#public-void-settag-object-tag):

> public void setTag (Object tag) 
>   Sets the tag for the marker.
>   You can use this property to associate an arbitrary Object with this marker. For example, the Object can contain data about what the marker represents